# How to hide a message button in a website on logout action?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

In my website, I want to hide my message button after logging out, message option should be disabled after logout..Using Javascript and PHP. People Can you please help me in this...

This is the button I want to hide after Logout

```
<div class="fixed-sidebar right fixed-sidebar-responsive">

   <div class="fixed-sidebar-right sidebar--small" id="sidebar-right-responsive">

       <a href="/messages" class="olympus-chat inline-items customHeaderMessage">
           <svg class="olymp-chat---messages-icon"><use xlink:href="/svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg#olymp-chat---messages-icon"></use></svg>
       </a>

   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can use `$_SESSION`

Comment: Can show some code part. What should be hidden.

Comment: I made some edits above, though I'm a frontend Developer, I dont Know PHP.

Comment: What framework or template engine you use? Do you use pure PHP & HTML?

Comment: NO, we can use javascript and jquery to code. please code this in javascript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions to hide message button by keeping a condition for that

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['login_user']= $username;
if ($_SESSION['login_user']!="admin") {
     // your code
} else {
     // your code
}
session_destroy();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to store the current user id in a sesion then using jquery you can check if the current user is not null then display the button otherwise you can hide it .

like say your button has an id of myButton, you can do this

```
<?php 
sesion_start() 
$currentUser = sesion['user'];
?>

<html>
<head>
<script>
var myButton = getElementById("myButton");
if(currentUser != null ){
myButton.show();
}
else{ myButton.hide()}
</script>
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

You will need to add current user to session on login and then destroy the session on logout.

Comment: can you please send the code in javascript or jquery

Comment: check between the script tags the js code is there what you do is to define the functions elsewhere

Comment: its not working, showing some error from PHP. Can we do this in Pure Javascript or Jquery?